# How can i detect if image i'm going to upload is a bitmask image?

Tags: javascript, php, webix

I'm going to set a bitmask image checker to ui.uploader of webix framework. Is there code that I can run before upload to check if an image is a bitmask?

I've searched the web but found nothing about it.

https://snippet.webix.com/acqc24mu

The result is simpel: If: the image I'm uploading is a bitmask image continue to upload. Else: Send a message.

Thanks
Cris

Comment: thanks @Marty for editing

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help you any further bud! Good luck!